# How to make a variable optional in blade template (laravel 8)

Tags: laravel

I get an error :

$count is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $count }} with {{ $count ?? '' }}

Here is my blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')


@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        @if ($count == 0 && !$count == '') 
            <h3>Δε βρέθηκαν eshops με τον όρο αναζήτησης : <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $q }}</span>.
                <br> 
                Θα κάνουμε ό,τι μπορούμε να καλύψουμε την ανάγκη σας !<h3>
                <h5>Μπορείτε να δοκιμάσετε με ένα νέο όρο αναζήτησης ή επιβεβαιώστε την ορθογραφία σας.</h5>
                <a href="{{ route('home')  }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Δοκιμάστε πάλι !</button></a>
        @else 
        <h3>Βρέθηκαν <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $count }}</span> eshops με τον όρο αναζήτησης : <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $q }}</span></h3>
        @endif
        @foreach($eshops as $eshop)
           @include('includes.eshop')
           <br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: you have to have it defined, pass it to your view, or you will have to check if it is `isset` in some way

Comment: Thanks. I did :  @if (isset($count) && $count == 0) and solved

Answer (score 1):

You could use the blade `@isset` or `@empty` as well:

```
@isset($count)
    // $count is defined and is not null...
@endisset

@empty($count)
    // $count is "empty"...
@endempty
```

More info can be found here: [If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements)

Answer (score 1):

I think shortest and most elegant would be:

```
{{ $variable ?? '' }}
```

or

```
{{ $variable ?? null }}
```

or

```
{{ $variable ?? 'Default value' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{ $count }}` try this `{{ isset($count) ? $count : ''}}`

Answer (score 0):

// Try this method.
{{( !empty($count)) ? $count : 'No Logs Found'  }}

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This.

```
@if(isset($count))
    .....
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use anonymous components. At the top of your blade declare a `@props` directive and assign count a default value, e.g. `@props(['count' => 0])` and in your blade you could then use `@if( $count > 0 )`. Passing a value for `$counts` from the controller will overwrite the default and it should work as expected.

Originally answered [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/optional-properties-in-blade-component?page=1&replyId=621130) by `andersb`