# Laravel: Optional variable in blade template?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a quiz app and when I press add question button the error `Undefined variable: question $question is undefined. Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $question }} with {{ $question ?? '' }}` occurs. The error appear for line 13 and 17:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title'); !!}
    {{ Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-editor', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category'); !!}
    <select class="form-control" id="category_id" name="category_id">
        <option selected="selected" value="">---Pick a Category---</option>
        @foreach($categories as $key => $cat)
            @if(!empty($child_categories[$key]))
                <optgroup label="{{ $cat }}">
                    @foreach($child_categories[$key] as $ckey => $ccat)
                        <option value="{{ $ckey }}" {{ $question->category_id == $ckey ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $ccat }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </optgroup>
            @else
                <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $question->category_id == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $cat }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('question_type', 'Question Type'); !!}
    {!! Form::select('question_type', ['regular' => 'Regular Question', 'photo' => 'Photo Question'], null, ['id' => 'question_type', 'class' => 'form-control']); !!}
</div>
@if($btntitle == 'Update Question')
    <div class="alert alert-success question_image" style="{{ isset($question) && $question->question_type == 'photo' ? 'display: block;' : 'display: none;' }}">
        Upload image if you want to ovewrite existing one(if any), otherwise leave that field blank
    </div>    
@endif
```

Comment: Which exactly line and what is the error message? You're already using `isset($question) && $question->....` at the bottom, that should work everywhere

Comment: I am getting error at the 13th and 17th line it only says Undefined variable: question          $question is undefined

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This has nothing to do with Python or Android.

Comment: What is line 13 and 17 to you?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770512/how-to-make-a-variable-optional-in-blade-template-laravel-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a variable optional in blade template (laravel 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770512/how-to-make-a-variable-optional-in-blade-template-laravel-8)